# How to get table values from template to subroutine?

Tags: perl, dancer

I have one table with table_id="mytable"

i need to send all the rows of the table in the action subroutine after clicking on submit. In the subroutine, I need to insert the rows one by one into a table after modifying some values.

What is the easiest way to do this?

---

**My real template:**

```html
<form method="post" action="/savesmop" >
<section class="wrapper">
  <h1>Select Items and add components</h1>
  <ul class="tabs">
<% FOREACH Component_Id IN components.keys.nsort %>
    <li><a href="#tab<% components.$Component_Id.Component_Id %>"><% components.$Component_Id.Component_Name %></a></li>
<% END %>
  </ul>
  <div class="clr"></div>
  <section class="block">
<% FOREACH Component_Id IN **components.keys.nsort** %>
    <article id="tab<% components.$Component_Id.Component_Id %>">
 <% FOREACH ACTIVITY_ID IN activities.keys.nsort %>
  <% IF activities.$ACTIVITY_ID.Component_Id == components.$Component_Id.Component_Id  %>
         <input class="toggle-box" id="t<% activities.$ACTIVITY_ID.ACTIVITY_ID %>" name="t<% activities.$ACTIVITY_ID.ACTIVITY_ID %>" type="checkbox" >
   <label for="t<% activities.$ACTIVITY_ID.ACTIVITY_ID %>"><% activities.$ACTIVITY_ID.ACTIVITY_NAME %>
     <input type="button" class="btnsmall1" onclick="addRow('<% activities.$ACTIVITY_ID.ACTIVITY_ID %>')" value="+" />
              <input type="button" class="btnsmall2" onclick="deleteRow('<% activities.$ACTIVITY_ID.ACTIVITY_ID %>')" value="X" />
   </label>
   <div>
   
   <table id="<% activities.$ACTIVITY_ID.ACTIVITY_ID %>" name="<% activities.$ACTIVITY_ID.ACTIVITY_ID %>">
   <tr><td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
   <% FOREACH ATTRIBUTE_ID IN attributes.keys.nsort %>
    <% IF attributes.$ATTRIBUTE_ID.ACTIVITY_ID == activities.$ACTIVITY_ID.ACTIVITY_ID %>
     
     <td>
     <% IF attributes.$ATTRIBUTE_ID.ATTRIBUTE_NAME == 'Object Type' %>
     <select id="<% attributes.$ATTRIBUTE_ID.ATTRIBUTE_ID %>" name="<% attributes.$ATTRIBUTE_ID.ATTRIBUTE_ID %>">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Select Object Type</option>
     <option value="TABLE">TABLE</option>
     <option value="VIEW">VIEW</option>
     <option value="OTHER">OTHER</option>
     </select>
     <% ELSIF attributes.$ATTRIBUTE_ID.ATTRIBUTE_NAME == 'SVN Path' %>
     <input size="90" type="TEXT" placeholder="<% attributes.$ATTRIBUTE_ID.ATTRIBUTE_NAME %>" id="<% attributes.$ATTRIBUTE_ID.ATTRIBUTE_ID %>" name="<% attributes.$ATTRIBUTE_ID.ATTRIBUTE_ID %>"/>
     <% ELSE %>
     <input type="TEXT" placeholder="<% attributes.$ATTRIBUTE_ID.ATTRIBUTE_NAME %>" id="<% attributes.$ATTRIBUTE_ID.ATTRIBUTE_ID %>" name="<% attributes.$ATTRIBUTE_ID.ATTRIBUTE_ID %>"/>
     <% END %>
     </td>
    <% END %>
   <% END %>
   </tr>
   </table>
   </div>
   <br>
  <% END %>
 <% END %>
     </article>
<% END %>
</section>
</section>

<input class="btn2" type="submit" value="SAVE" />

</form>
```

There are 3 hashes i am selecting from 3 different database tables, and looping through them to dynamically generate this template.

As you can see there are multiple tables in each list item and number of columns are also different in each table. What I did in the javascript is to clone the 1st row of the table while adding one row. I could not figure out how to increment the name tag of each text input by 1 while adding a new row in the javascript addrow function.

Below is my javascript function:

```
function deleteRow(tableID) 
    { 
        try
        { 
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) 
            {

                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];

                if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked)
                {
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(e){alert(e);}
    }

function addRow(tableID) 
    {

      var table = document.getElementById(tableID); // find table to append to

      var row = document.getElementById(tableID).rows.item(0); // find row to copy

      var clone = row.cloneNode(true); // copy children too
      clone.id = "newID"; // change id or other attributes/contents
      table.appendChild(clone); // add new row to end of table
       }
```

Comment: You need to give a realistic example or no one will want to, or be able to help you. And show your best attempt at doing this - Stack Overflow is a knowledge base and you shouldn't think of it as a place to get your work done for free

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have added one example for your reference. Did not add example before as I am new to dancer and I thought this is very general and basic question. Thanks.

Comment: Is my question still not clear?? Can someone please tell me what else I have to do to make it understandable?

Comment: Here is what I am **guessing* from your question: There is a form that is displayed in a table-like fasion on the page. User can add extra rows. User fills in data. When user submits, all the data should be inserted to the DB. Why your question is unclear: it took me a bit to differentiate between db-table and html-table, you are not showing the JS function that is essential, you're not saying if this is Dancer or Dancer2 and which template-engine you are using. The `id` of the table is irelevant to the backend. Only the `name`s of the `input` fields are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are not saying which Dancer version you are using, I will assume you are using the [first version of Dancer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer) (and not [Dancer2](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2)).

It looks like you are unsure about how forms work when they are submitted via GET or POST in general. That's not specific to Dancer, but very generic to how the HTTP protocol works, and tied to HTML.

If there is a form in your HTML document, the form elements like `<input>` and `<textarea>` need to have the `name` attribute. That is what will go into the request. The `id` attribute is only for CSS and JS (this is simplified).

```
<form action="/save" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="foo" id="input-foo" />
  <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

If you enter *bar* and hit that button, your browser will navigate to:

```
/save?foo=bar
```

If there is no `name` attribute on an `<input>`, it will be ignored by the browser.

```
<form action="/save" method="GET">
  <input type="text" id="input-foo" />
  <input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

This will lead you to:

```
/save
```

That is also useful if you don't want the `value` of your `submit` button to show up. Just don't give it a `name` attribute.

Ok, now you have multiple rows of input fields. Those are dynamic. You assigned integer numbers as `id`s for the `<table>` and the `<input>` elements. That is weird, but should not be a problem. But there are **no `name` attributes**.

You should give each `<input>` a distinct name. For example, use names related to your placeholders.

```
<table id="101">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Database Name" name="dbname-1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Database Appx Size" id="appx-1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Rate of growth" id="growth-1" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now there is one row with three distinct names: `dbname-1`, `appx-1` and `growth-1`.

Let's look at the JavaScript to add new rows. I'm not going to show it here, but what it should do is include the `name` attribute and *increment* the numbers. The next row should have these names: `dbname-2`, `appx-2` and `growth-2`. You get the pattern here.

Finally, we need to do stuff in the Perl code. We'll get all the parameters, filter them down to only the three field-types we are interested in, and then iterate those to insert them. We'll also make sure they are not empty.

```
post '/savesmop' => sub {

    # get all the parameters
    my %values = params;

    # remove unwanted ones that don't belong to the rows
    foreach my $key ( keys %values ) {
        delete $values{$key} unless $key =~ m/^(?:dbname|appx|growth)-/;
    }

    my $dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbid', 'user', 'pwd' ) or die $DBI::errstr;
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE_Fact VALUES (?,?,?)") or die $dbh->errstr;

    # iterate over the dbnames only
    foreach my $dbname ( grep {m/^dbname/} sort keys %values ) {

        # field should not be empty
        next unless $values{$dbname};

        # fetch the number from the dbname...
        ( undef, my $id ) = split /-/, $dbname;

        # ... and the other two should exist and not be empty also
        next unless my $appx = $values{ 'appx-' . $id };
        next unless my $pwd  = $values{ 'pwd-' . $id };

        # now insert
        $sth->execute( @values{ $dbname, $appx, $pwd } ) or die $dbh->errstr;
    }
    template "savesmop";

};
```

The point about this is that you do not need to know how many there are. A `while` loop is not the best approach to do insert stuff into a database. Ususally you iterate data with a `for` loop. Perl's `foreach my $item (@list)` syntax is especially useful, because you do not have to care how long the array/list is.

---

A few side-nodes:

- Have you considered using [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class)? There is a good plugin for that called [Dancer::Plugin::DBIC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::DBIC) that makes it easy to use in your Dancer app. DBIx::Class has some learning curve, but it is worth it!
- If you are intimidated by an object relation mapper or think it's overkill, take a look at [Dancer::Plugin::Database](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer::Plugin::Database) instead. It helps abstract the `$dbh` away and you don't need to care about connecting.
- If you don't want plugins at all (which would not be a smart decision, it's always nice if others have done the work and it is well-tested!), at least don't make a fresh connection to the db in your route handler. Dancer runs persistently (unless you run it as a CGI) so it will benefit from keeping the connection open. Connect to the DB at the top of the application code and keep it in the [`config`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer#config). It's weird, but more efficient.

  ```
  use Dancer;
  use DBI;

  config 'dbh' => DBI->connect('...') or die $DBH::errstr;

  get '/foo' => sub {
    config->dbh->prepare('select ...');
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot simbabque for the nice explanation. I have missed the name tag while creating the example. Its there indeed. But what i figured out is my javascript function adds the new row with same names for each input boxes in the table. I have added my real template and javascript functions and other details  in the question. And I am using DANCER2.

Comment: @Rony you would have saved me some time had you said that earlier. Anyway, the answer is still correct if it's D2. The `param` works the same, and you can apply the same principle. I would however change the JS and not copy the data. Instead, create fresh elements. Employing a JS framework like jQuery makes that very easy.

Comment: Apologies for that. Tell me one thing: If I do "my %values = params; " "values" will contain all the rows from all the tables? If yes then how would I loop through each table and then inner-loop through each rows? Actually, I am not familiar with the key that you are using here: "foreach my $key ( keys %values )". or here : "foreach my $dbname ( grep {m/^dbname/} sort keys %values )" .

Comment: Can you point me to a link for this? : "I would however change the JS and not copy the data. Instead, create fresh elements. Employing a JS framework like jQuery makes that very easy."   I am not that comfortable with jquery( always had my work done with js only)  and I have googled before posting this. Was not able to locate a related example.

Comment: @Rony so you have one table per article and those can have multiple rows. Just prefix the article-id/uuid/whatever is the primary information for an article in the `name` of the input fields and then suffix or praefix the number of the rows, starting by `1` for each article. If your SQL needs to care what article it is, i.e. you have different db tables for those, you need to separate them in the backend. If not, you just need to extract the article identification from the key and use it as one of the values in the SQL.

Comment: @Rony re the jquery: https://jquery.com/. Also see [the jquery tag wiki on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88017/discussion-between-rony-and-simbabque).